# snowflake: Materialized view on stage?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible to create a materialized view on top of Stage (loaded CSV files) or alternate to create MV on direct files without a table?

example:

create or replace materialized view mv_ext_v1 as

select metadata$filename, metadata$file_row_number, $1, $2 from @newstage order by 1;

error:
Materialized view not supported over a stage.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't define a `MATERIALIZED VIEW` over a staged file.

But you can define [Materialized Views over External Tables](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/tables-external-intro.html#materialized-views-over-external-tables), which are the same, but in an extra wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. As stated in the [Snowflake docs](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/views-materialized.html#limitations-on-creating-materialized-views) a materialized view is limited to query only a single table and no other objects.

Answer (score 0):

Wonder if you have looked at materialized view over external table (which are just files on stage also):
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/tables-external-intro.html#materialized-views-over-external-tables